# .NET winforms bug (savefiledialog)?

Tags: c#, winforms

The following example simply shows and SaveFileDialog on a ToolStripButton click event. If I pre-make the SaveFileDialog and then double-click the ToolStripButton, the application stackoverflows. Seems like a bug in Winforms to me. Not optimistic on getting a fix or even a response from MS (even a couple years ago they just responded "no more bug fixes for winforms" when i reported a bug), so I'd just like some opinions on whether this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToolStripDoubleClickSaveDialog
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         sfd.ShowDialog(this);
      }

      private void InitializeComponent()
      {
         this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
         this.toolStripButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
         this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
         this.SuspendLayout();
         // 
         // toolStrip1
         // 
         this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripButton1});
         this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
         this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
         this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 25);
         this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
         // 
         // toolStripButton1
         // 
         this.toolStripButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
         this.toolStripButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
         this.toolStripButton1.Name = "toolStripButton1";
         this.toolStripButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 22);
         this.toolStripButton1.Text = "double click me";
         this.toolStripButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripButton1_Click);
         // 
         // Form1
         // 
         this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
         this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
         this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
         this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
         this.Name = "Form1";
         this.Text = "Form1";
         this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
         this.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.PerformLayout();

      }

      private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip1;
      private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton toolStripButton1;
   }
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1450200/2596334).

Comment: Ummm...I know what a stackoverflow exception is...that wasn't the question.

Comment: What is the code that can reproduce the issue? Your code posted looks fine.

Comment: This usually happens to me when my event handler is accidently calling the event itself. And it ends up looping in a circle triggering the events. Sometimes I will have a button where I first implement the logic, and then secondly a tool strip item which calls that button, but I will inadvertently call the tool strip event... Thus a loop occurs.

Comment: @gunr2171 the OP's code repros the issue for me - it crashes LINQPad when I doubleclick the button, anyway. Did you try it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, yes. And I don't get any errors. The popup form won't allow me to click the button for the second time because the popup has already appeared and taken control. I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: @gunr2171 I just tried in VS2013, `System.StackOverflowException was unhandled _HResult=-2147023895` on the line `sfd.ShowDialog();`. Perhaps your computer is faster than mine, or your mouse is slower.

Comment: @gunr2171 It didn't happen 100% for me, but if there is any lag before the dialog is open after a double click, it reaches the .ShowDialog() twice and triggers the error. I'm guessing the slower the computer, the easier it is to repo.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so the issue comes about when the control is Doubleclicked because it's set to open the dialog on a single click and both click events are attempting to open the dialog at the same time. My guess is that while the dialog is loading, the app goes into a short idle state briefly before the dialog opens, long enough to allow for the other event to get called as well, causing an error when it calls `ShowDialog()` twice.

To prevent this, you can get the [`System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime.Lease`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.lifetime.ilease%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the window and double check it's not active before showing it.

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime;
//.....
private SaveFileDialog sfd;
private ILease sfdLease;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfdLease= (ILease)sfd.InitializeLifetimeService();
}
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sfdLease.CurrentState != LeaseState.Active)
        sfd.ShowDialog(this);
}
```